# Declaration to make PHP script completely Unicode-friendly

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8

Remembering to do all the stuff you need to do in PHP to get it to work properly with Unicode is far too tricky, tedious, and error-prone, so I'm looking for the trick to get PHP to magically upgrade absolutely everything it possibly can from *musty old ASCII byte mode* into *modern Unicode character mode,* all at once and by using just one simple declaration.

The idea is to modernize PHP scripts to work with Unicode without having to clutter up the source code with a bunch of confusing alternate function calls and special regexes. Everything should just **“Do The Right Thing”** with Unicode, no questions asked.

Given that the goal is **maximum Unicodeness with minimal fuss,** this declaration must *at least* do these things (plus anything else I’ve forgotten that furthers the overall goal):

- The PHP script source is itself in considered to be in UTF‑8 (eg, strings and regexes).
- All input and output is automatically converted to/from UTF‑8 as needed, and with a normalization option (eg, all input normalized to NFD and all output normalized to NFC).
- All functions with Unicode versions use those instead (eg, `Collator::sort` for `sort`).
- All byte functions (eg, `strlen`, `strstr`, `strpos`, and `substr`) work like the corresponding character functions (eg, `mb_strlen`, `mb_strstr`, `mb_strpos`, and `mb_substr`).
- All regexes and regexy functions transparently work on Unicode (ie, like all the preggers have `/u` tacked on implicitly, and things like `\w` and `\b` and `\s` all work on Unicode *[the way The Unicode Standard **requires** them to work](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties),* etc).

For extra credit :), I'd like there to be a way to “upgrade” this declaration to *full grapheme mode.*  That way the byte or character functions become grapheme functions (eg, `grapheme_strlen`, `grapheme_strstr`, `grapheme_strpos`, and `grapheme_substr`), and the regex stuff works on proper graphemes (ie, `.` — or even `[^abc]` — matches a Unicode grapheme cluster no matter how many code points it contains, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That **full-unicode** thing was precisely the idea of **PHP 6** -- which has been *canceled* more than one year ago.

So, no, there is no way of getting all that -- except by using the right functions, and remembering that characters are not the same as bytes.

One thing that might help with you fourth point, though, is the [**Function Overloading Feature**][1] of the `mbstring` extension *(quoting)* :

> mbstring supports a 'function
> overloading' feature which enables you
> to add multibyte awareness to such an
> application without code modification
> by overloading multibyte counterparts
> on the standard string functions.
>
> For example, `mb_substr()` is
> called instead of `substr()` if
> function overloading is enabled.

Comment: Really? It was *cancelled?* Why in the world would anybody want to cancel something so important, now that virtually the entire web is Unicode now? :(

Comment: If there isn’t already a way to do it (I’d thought there already was), then I would also accept an answer that showed how to code up such a thing.

Comment: It has *(even if I'm not sure if "canceled" is the right word, that's the basic idea)* ; see http://news.php.net/php.internals/47120 ;;; how to code a thing such as "all in unicode" ? Well, that was the idea of PHP 6 -- and quite a lot of work...

Comment: If there is a `mbstring.func_overload`, it seems to me that there should be a way to make that work for other functions, too, including the `grapheme_*` ones. Similarly, the deprecated `mb_regex_set_options` seems to be just  what is needed — save that it doesn’t include `/u` for `preg_*`. Why is it so much work? Is the problem that PHP’s module/extension mechanism isn’t rich enough to make such extensions natural and easy to write? Can’t you just add something to a table somewhere, especially in the first case? Thank you, Pascal.

Comment: I suppose you could use some mecanism like the overloading used by mbstring, to just re-define all PHP functions ; but I let you imagine how much time it would take you to re-code all those functions, in C ;-)  *(that was part of the PHP 6 development, btw, going over all PHP functions in order to make sure they would work with unicode)*

Comment: Darn, I think I’ve found what I was dimly remembering.  It was `unicode_semantics = On` from [this proposal](http://news.php.net/php.internals/17771). I guess that never happened, then.  Did they really end up using nasty UTF-16 internally? I hope not: UTF-8 makes for smaller HTML or XML even for CJK, because of the density of ASCII mark-up.

Comment: UTF-16 was what would have been used for PHP 6.

Comment: That would have been unfortunate: UTF-16 is a horrible mess: UTF-16 has all the disadvantages of UTF-8 and none of the advantages of UTF-8. It’s very error-prone, too.

Answer (score 5):

> All byte functions (eg, strlen, strstr, strpos, and substr) work like the corresponding character functions (eg, mb_strlen, mb_strstr, mb_strpos, and mb_substr).

This isn't a good idea.

Unicode strings cannot transparently replace byte strings. Even when you are correctly handling all human-readable text as Unicode, there are still important uses for byte strings in handling file and network data that isn't character-based, and interacting with systems that explicitly use bytes.

For example, spit out a header `'Content-Length: '.strlen($imageblob)` and you're going to get brokenness if that's suddenly using codepoint semantics.

You still need to have both `mb_strlen` *and* `strlen`, and you have to know which is the right one to use in each circumstance; there's not a single switch you can throw to automatically do the right thing.

This is why IMO the approach of having a single string datatype that can be treated with byte or codepoint semantics is generally a mistake. Languages that provide separate datatypes for byte strings (with byte semantics), and character strings (with Unicode codepoint semantics(*)) tend to be more consistent.

(*: or UTF-16 code unit semantics if unlucky)

Comment: Perl seems to get by with `length` for everything. You just have to encode from internal logical characters to UTF-8 at times: `print "Content-Length: ", length(utf8_encode($payload))`. But those occasions are rare, so having the normal `strlen` be bytes not characters is a Huffman failure: the short thing should be the common thing.