# check if string contains any character other than what's allowed

Tags: php, regex

In username - I want to only allow alphanumeric characters and 10 other UTF8 characters that I want. What would be a proper way to do this? Would UTF8 be a problem with preg functions and do I need to use another method?

Thanks

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765093/declaration-to-make-php-script-completely-unicode-friendly) how to make this Just Do The Right Thing, and learned that it’s rather prickly to get everything quite right.

If you can’t get `/\w/u` to work right for you on Unicode, it is mostly like `/[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}]/u`.

Answer (score 0):

Preg is your best bet.  Do something like this replacing the random japanese characters, I used, with your choice of allowed characters.

```
if (preg_match('/[\x{0030}-\x{0039}\x{0041}-\x{005A}\x{0061}\-u007A]+/u', $subject)) {
return true;
}
return false;
```

If you need help with regex expressions then I recomend regexbuddy, which you can get at regexbuddy.com

Comment: But that isn’t Unicode for Alphabetics, you know.  `a-z` is one of those code-smell bugs.

Comment: Sorry about that. The above is edited to use unicode character maps. This is the Unicode equivalent of [0-9A-Za-z]+ you'll need to add the correct mappings for your desired characters.

Answer (score 0):

For proper Unicode support (including proper case-awareness) you need to use the `'/u'` modifier IIRC. But, but, but: be aware that most *other* PHP functions will treat PHP strings as byte strings (not character strings), which means if you're doing stuff like `stripos()` you will get offsets in byte indices and not character indices, and they will not work reliably for malformed UTF-8 (because they match byte sequences rather than character sequences).

Also, note that UTF-8 literals may not be such a good idea if you need to run this script somewhere that doesn't use UTF-8 as system locale (Windows).